# Passing ClaimsPrincipal from Controller to Service

Tags: .net-core, clean-architecture

I'm rather new to .NET Core, but I'm trying to write my code as adherent to SOLID principals as possible.

I have a scenario where a user who has registered with my site may decide to login with a Facebook account that uses the same email; which throws an error, because the email field in my users table is unique.

My solution to this has been to create some sort of associative table Users_Facebook like so...

[image]

In my controller where I'm registering the user; to get the userId, I have implemented a service to (A. Check the user_facebook table for an existing user or (B. To associate the Facebook userId with an existing user based on email.

```cs
            [Route("api/Users")]
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<int> RegisterUser()
            {
                var userId = await userService.GetUserIdAsync(User);
                var email = User.Claims.First(e => e.Type == "emails").Value;
                var user = await _unitOfWork.Users.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);

                // Check contacts to see if one needs to be associated with a user
                var contact = await _unitOfWork.Contacts.GetContactByEmail(email);
                ...
```

Service snippet:

```cs
            public async Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(ClaimsPrincipal authedUser)
            {
                var userId = authedUser.Claims.First(e => e.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                var email = authedUser.Claims.First(e => e.Type == "emails").Value;

                var identityProvider = authedUser.HasClaim(e => e.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider") ?
                    authedUser.Claims.First(e => e.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider").Value : null;
                ...
```

My question is, is there anything wrong with this? Is this okay that I'm passing the ClaimsPrincipal to my service? Or am I breaking some sort of best practice? If I'm completely off, can someone suggest a better way of doing such a thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldnt pass the ClaimsPrincipal into the method. Pass IHttpContextAccessor into the constructor of your service instead. That way it can be registered in the DI container by doing this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then in your service class inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` like this:

```
public class MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
}
```

This means you have access to the current context from within your class without having to pass it in via the method.

To access the current logged in user just access it like this:

`var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;`

Comment: This got me to where I wanted; however I noticed I had to do the following to make it work...

context.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(e => e.Type == "<scheme_url>").Value; At any rate, thank you.